# Java Servlets and Commons FileUpload getParameter after Request being handle

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons

I have an Application in Java EE using *Apache Commons File Upload API*.  Everything is going smoothly so far but I have a question.

I have some kind of validation on the server side - if there is any problem I have to send the user to the previous page and inform the problem to the user.  Also I have to load the data into the form, but when I use `request.getParameter("key")` in the JSP, it is returning `null`.

I have tested with the request not being handled by `commons-fileupload` and I see the result.

My question is how to keep the `request.getParameter("key")` and send it back to the client after the request is handled by `org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload`?

`<%out.println(request.getParameter("cedula"));%>` returning `null` after request being handle by the API

Comment: Are you sure that you handle it in the right scope?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048939/file-upload-with-servletfileupload-parserequest/13049144#13049144)

Comment: Yeah Roman i have test it without request handle before commons and i see the result but when commons handle the request returns null. i need to see the value in a JSP i store all them in request.setAttribute() and i see it in the Jsp i dont know if is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. The whole HTTP request is been sent in a different format which only Apache Commons FileUpload can handle. The `request.getParameter("name")` won't work for any of the parameters, also not the regular ones.

You should be using the very same Apache Commons FileUpload API to extract the values from regular input fields. You should normally do that when the `item.isFormField()` line in their code examples returns `true` (extracting the uploaded file is to be done when it returns `false`, you've likely already implemented that part).

Alternatively, if you're already on Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), then you can also just use the `@MultipartConfig` annotation on the servlet, so that you can get the uploaded files by `request.getPart("name")` and continue using `request.getParameter("name")` for regular input fields.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: Hello Thanks for response. yeah i have done with item.isFormField() in servlet my question is how do it in a JSP(a little more coding). i have store in request.setAttribute is a good approach? thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello i have another question. i need to store the file(Picture) on DB. i have handle the file very good my question is. i have to write to Disk(Folder)? or can i direct store in a byte[] without use fi.write(PhotoFile) there is a method like getBytes() which returns me the bytes for i can handle to the DB directly. thanks a lot

Comment: here is the code to saving in byte[] instead of File Folder before being save to DB.`code`byte[] Array=(IOUtils.toByteArray(fi.getInputStream()));`code`

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you use `getParameter()` instead of `getAttribute()`
2. When validation errors happen the request is redirected, this means a new request object is sent and you need to supply request attributes again.

The same way you did it when the action is dispatched to JSP. If you want to pass the parameter then then you should supply it in the attribute `action` of the `<form>` tag.

It seems framework dependent but you could try. Note, in the JSP if you use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) you can try `${param}` to access the parameters and `${attr}` to access attributes instead if *scriplets'* `getParameter()`, if you really want to pass it via URL. There's also [good art](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html) on JSTL.

Comment: Yes that's exactly i did. and is working perfect thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answer helped you then you should mark it as accepted. The checkbox I'd on the left of the answer. Also it's worth to vote up the answer that helped you the same to help others to choose the correct answer.