# Upload image to server in GWT project using Servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets, file-upload

I am developing a GWT application which, among its other functions, permits the user to upload an image file and to store it on the server.
So far, that's what I've done..

SERVLET

```
public class ImageUploadService extends HttpServlet {

private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    wlog("INFO: è partita la servlet");

    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        wlog("ERR: non è multipart!");
    ServletFileUpload fileUpld = new ServletFileUpload();

    try {
        wlog("INFO: itero file");
        FileItemIterator fileIt = fileUpld.getItemIterator(request);
        while (fileIt.hasNext()) {

            wlog("INFO: trovato file");
            FileItemStream fileStream = fileIt.next();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    fileStream.openStream(), 4096);
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("immagineSegnalazione.jpg"));

            byte[] buf = new byte[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = in.read(buf, 0, MAX_FILE_SIZE)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void wlog(String s) {
    System.out.println("UPLOAD SERVLET " + s);
}
}
```

MODULE ON CLIENT SIDE

```
            [...]

        PopupPanel inserisciSegnalazionePopup = new PopupPanel();
    final FormPanel uploadForm = new FormPanel();
    uploadForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    uploadForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    inserisciSegnalazionePopup.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
    VerticalPanel holder = new VerticalPanel();
    holder.add(new Label("se puoi, allega una foto della segnalazione"));
    final FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
    uploadForm.add(fu);
    holder.add(uploadForm);
    uploadForm.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "imageUpload");
    Button inviaBtn = new Button("INVIA SEGNALAZIONE");
    inviaBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO check file is image and size and other stuff


            uploadForm.submit();
        }

    });
    holder.add(inviaBtn);

            [...]
```

..plus I've rightly made the changes needed on web.xml
The Servlet is correctly called and the method doPost() starts, but the FileItemIterator is always empty, as if there were no files at all..
Can someone guess what's wrong? I can't really see where's the mistake
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is...
Simply add .setName() to the FileUpload widget

Answer (score 1):

just guessing I would say the request is parsed somewhere befor you use it. Try taking a look at that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13048939/2351943) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049027/2351943) to it, it seems to like it was nearly the same problem.

Sarajog

Comment: The request is never parsed before the part of code I've shown..I tried to change the code as suggested in the link you provided me, but the iterator still will be empty..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ??

```
Iterator<FileItem> iterator = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator();
```

Comment: I followed Sarajog's suggestion and yours, but the behaviour is exactly the same..