# Unable to find setter method for attribute in struts-html.tld

Tags: java, struts, taglib

i was updating struts tag lib for file attribute as i need to enable multiple file add option to struts tag like this `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" ... />`

i checked the taglib file `Struts-html.tld` and found file tag and added new attribute

```
<attribute>
<name>multiple</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

now i am having an exception  `Unable to find setter method for attribute: multiple` can any one help also tell what is `rtexprvalue` and its purpose.

Also how we will get it in java.

Comment: You need to update code as well not only tld.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, But where to update code... ???

Comment: Probably `FileTag` or something like that. But you are better off just using plain html tags.

Comment: yes, im using plain HTML, but can get only one file on java side... can u plz also tell how to get all files on java side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13049144/573032