# List<FileItem> is null when uploading file

Tags: java, file-upload, fileitem

I am trying to store a file along with two other values which are inputted in the text fields (orderid2 and remarks) in the database. However, the List< FileItem > is null. I do not know what is wrong with my code.. It is not doing the `while` loop.

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();
    if(item.isFormField()) {
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    String value = item.getString();
    System.out.println(name + " " + value);
        if(name.equals("orderid2"))
            order.setOrderID(Integer.parseInt(value));
        else if(name.equals("remarks"))
            order.setRemarks(value);
    }
}
```

P.S.
I actually think that the problem is in the request variable. I have this whole code in my servlet inside this function `protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, FileUploadException, SQLException {`
I do not really know what should be the parameter of the `upload.parseRequest()`. I just copied this somewhere

Comment: Can you put in a println statement before your if statement? Just check and verify that if it is actually hitting the while loop and not stopping in your if statement

Comment: @ryekayo It is not hitting the while loop

Comment: What is the request variable? That is not shown anywhere in your code. Can you add that in your question?

Comment: Are you in servlet parsing a multipart/form-data stream?

Comment: List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);   - Means you are trying to assign multiple files at a time to the List. I don't exactly know if this is wrong or not. Try to get 1 file at a time. For example see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048939/file-upload-with-servletfileuploads-parserequest

Comment: After seeing your edit I can say that : upload.parseRequest(request); is causing you the error.Go to the link I have provided in my earlier comment and see how the FileItem is handled there

Comment: @TheGuest I tried the one in the link but it is still not hitting the while loop

Comment: @nubteens Check whether you are successfully getting the file into your 'List' or not. For example try printing out List.lengt() i.e. items.length() and see what's there in the List